# No puedo modificar el margen derecho de mi página web

Tags: html, css

```css
@media (max-width:600px){

    body {
    background-color: rgb(56, 239, 10);
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0; 
    margin-right: -100px;
    }
```

Cuando despliego mi página web en modo dispositivo móvil, me crea un margen derecho el cual no he podido remover.

He verificado el contenido y todo está en línea dentro del parámetro que debería tener en modo móvil: es todo el borde de color verde que continúa en toda la página.

Sin embargo, el valor de "margin-right" no se aplica a la derecha, aunque a la izquierda sí.

¿Tienen alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Debes agregar tu código CSS y HTML del problema. Así no se puede adivinar donde o que es el problema.

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Recuerda que debes demostrar que has investigado previamente antes de recurrir a preguntar. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En ese código estas ejecutando margin y margin-right al mismo tiempo puedes hacerlo de diferentes formas:

aplicando margin, este modificara el margen de los 4 lados:

```
@media (max-width:600px){

    body {
    background-color: rgb(56, 239, 10);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 1em;
    }
```

o aplicándolo a cada lado con margin:

```
@media (max-width:600px){

    body {
    background-color: rgb(56, 239, 10);
    padding: 0px;
    /* Arriba | Derecha | Abajo | Izquierda */
    margin: 0px 1em 0px 1em;
    }
```